# How correctly built an object graph based on multi level join in Slick?

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I have a model structure as following:

```
Group -> Many Parties -> Many Participants
```

In on of the API calls I need to get single groups with parties and it's participants attached.

This whole structure is built on 4 tables:

- group
- party
- party_participant
- participant

Naturally, with SQL it's a pretty straight forward join that combines all of them. And this is exactly what I am trying to do with slick.
Mu method is dao class looks something like this:

```
def findOneByKeyAndAccountIdWithPartiesAndParticipants(key: UUID, accountId: Int): Future[Option[JourneyGroup]] = {
    val joins = JourneyGroups.groups join
                Parties.parties on (_.id === _.journeyGroupId) joinLeft
                PartiesParticipants.relations on (_._2.id === _.partyId) joinLeft
                Participants.participants on (_._2.map(_.participantId) === _.id)

    val query = joins.filter(_._1._1._1.accountId === accountId).filter(_._1._1._1.key === key)

    val q = for {
      (((journeyGroup, party), partyParticipant), participant) <- query
    } yield (journeyGroup, party, participant)

    val result = db.run(q.result)

    result ????
  }
```

The problem here, is that the `result` is type of `Future[Seq[(JourneyGroup, Party, Participant)]]`

However, what I really need is `Future[Option[JourneyGroup]]`

Note: case classes of `JourneyGroup` and `Party` have sequences for there children defined:

```
case class Party(id: Option[Int] = None,
                 partyType: Parties.Type.Value,
                 journeyGroupId: Int,
                 accountId: Int,
                 participants: Seq[Participant] = Seq.empty[Participant])
```

and

```
case class JourneyGroup(id: Option[Int] = None,
                        key: UUID,
                        name: String,
                        data: Option[JsValue],
                        accountId: Int,
                        parties: Seq[Party] = Seq.empty[Party])
```

So they both can hold the descendants.

What is the correct way to convert to the result I need? Or am I completely in a wrong direction?

Also, is this statement is correct:
`Participants.participants on (_._2.map(_.participantId) === _.id)` ?

Comment: Yep, wrong direction. Slick is not an ORM which means there is no such thing as an object graph. See http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/orm-to-slick.html

Comment: Here is an example that could help you: http://olivebh.com/scala-play-slick.html.

Comment: @Roman I am not expecting Slick to build the graph for me, I want to build it myself, after the query :)

Comment: @insan-e That's kind of what I thought, but I hoped to have a shorter way of converting from list of tuples into object graph.

Comment: @ShurikAgulyansky Nope, can't do. That would be a real Object-Relational Mapping like JPA (Hibernate etc.) :)

Comment: I strongly recommend to read the article from the slick docs I linked to. Especially the paragraph about "Relationships". It's exactly what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
journeyGroupDao.findOneByKeyAndAccountIdWithPartiesAndParticipants(key, account.id.get) map { data =>

      val groupedByJourneyGroup = data.groupBy(_._1)

      groupedByJourneyGroup.map { case (group, rows) =>

        val parties = rows.map(_._2).distinct map { party =>
          val participants = rows.filter(r => r._2.id == party.id).flatMap(_._3)

          party.copy(participants = participants)

        }

          group.copy(parties = parties)

      }.headOption

    }
```

where DAO method's signature is:

```
def findOneByKeyAndAccountIdWithPartiesAndParticipants(key: UUID, accountId: Int): Future[Seq[(JourneyGroup, Party, Option[Participant])]]
```